# is it dangerous to create a branch with same name as a deleted branch?

Tags: git

I've been working on a feature in a branch; call it 'foo'. I'm done for now and merging it into master and would like to delete it locally and remotely. But sometime in the future I may start working on this feature again and will be tempted to create a new branch also called 'foo'.

I don't think this will be a problem for me, but if someone else has their own copy of my current foo branch, and then they try to pull after the new foo branch has been created, will they get screwed up?

Comment: A branch is only a reference. Worst case, their reference will be overwritten by yours. Whether one considers it being screwed up is debatable.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No, it's not a problem.

The behaviour would be the same, as if the branch has not been deleted: Git will try to merge (or rebase) them when someone pulls the *new* branch. If there are conflicts, they would be there in either case.

Branches are, simply, pointers to commits. If you delete a branch, and create another one with the same name later on another commit, this is the *same* as if you would *reset* it to that commit (`git reset`).